# React setState is not autopopulating the data when clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-config

I am learning Reach for web development. Goal: To have the button update the message 'The State' every time the button is clicked. I am not getting any errors or issues that would help me resolved the issue.

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "BigD",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  }
}


I have tried redoing the code step by step.
I tried updating the error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.

import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.stateHandler = this.stateHandler.bind(this);
  }

  stateHandler() {
    var item = 'The State';
    var dataArray = this.state.data;
    dataArray.push(item);
    this.setState({data: dataArray });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.data} </div>
        <button onClick={this.stateHandler}> Click here to update </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The should show this message just like in the course:
Click Button:
'TheStateTheStateTheState'

[image][image]I

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to show array directly. Use Array.prototype.join(' '), which will convert array in to a space separated string and will correctly render.
{this.state.data.join(' ')}  will fix the issue for you.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.stateHandler = this.stateHandler.bind(this);
  }

  stateHandler() {
    var item = 'The State';
    var dataArray = this.state.data;
    dataArray.push(item);
    this.setState({data: dataArray });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.data.join(' ')} </div>
        <button onClick={this.stateHandler}> Click here to update </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll have too loop throught `this.state.data` to display the values :

```
<div>{this.state.data.map(e => <div>{e}</div>)} </div>
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.stateHandler = this.stateHandler.bind(this);
  }

  stateHandler() {
    var item = 'The State';
    var dataArray = this.state.data;
    dataArray.push(item);
    this.setState({data: dataArray });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.data.map(e => <div>{e}</div>)} </div>
        <button onClick={this.stateHandler}> Click here to update </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

a better implementation of `stateHandler` would be :

```
stateHandler() {
  var item = 'The State';
  this.setState(prevState => ({data: [...prevState.data, item] }));
}
```